# NoMethodError in UpdateController#index

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Unable to find why RoR is giving the NoMethodError in UpdateController#index

I am trying to update a database table record from my controller method.

In my controller the code is:

```
currency = Currency.where(:code => code)
currency.rate = quote["LastTradePriceOnly"]
currency.save
```

My table definition is:

```
create_table :currencies do |t|
t.string  :code,  :null => false
t.string  :name
t.text  :description
t.float :rate
t.boolean :direct,  :default =>true
t.timestamps
```

The error that I am getting is 
    undefined method `rate=' for #

Any help would be highly appreciated,

Comment: What is `Currency.where(:code => code)` returning? It sounds like it's returning more than one record, which would make currency.rate = 'something' not work because it's a hash of results. Do a .inspect on it and see if it's a single resource or not.

Comment: @Magicmarkker -- Thanks ... currency = Currency.where(:code => code).first solved the error. Although there was only one record earlier also, wonder why it was treating as multiple results. Also any difference in using currency.rate or currency["rate"]?

Comment: Thought that might be the issue. No real difference, most people don't like typing out the brackets and quotes so why do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`where` returns an ActiveRecord relation, which basically behaves like an enumerable of models. If you only want one item, use `find`:

```
single_currency = Currency.find_by_code(code)
```